# Replace empty Day or Month or Year with Current Day or Month or Year in masked textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date

I have a masked textbox.

When a user enters his input and press the tab key. I want to check if he has entered a valid date or not?

I can check this by `IsDate` Function.

If it is invalid then which part of the date is invalid?

I cant get this. I mean I don't know how to get this.

If my above question is answered then I want to ask the user that his day or month or year is invalid. Do you want to replace that with current Day or Current Month Or Current Year?

Or even if user keeps the year blank then I want to have the current year in place of empty space.
or same with the month.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're asking the user to enter a date and they enter an incomplete or improperly formatted date shouldn't you alert them to this fact? Trying to guess what they *intended* to enter is usually a path leading to destruction.

Comment: +1 It's much more commonplace to just inform the user that they've entered an incorrect date, explain why, and alert them that they need to fix it before proceeding. You don't need to go into detail about which part of the date is incorrect.

Comment: Currently I am working on an accounting project where the year entered to be is fixed. And entering the whole date all the time is a tedious task. So if the user enters the date and month he doesn't have to enter the year. Also If he enters the date keeping month and year empty the month and year should be current month and current year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question.

```
Private Sub mskdTxtBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles mskdTxtBox1.Validating

        'Check If Day is entered.
        If mskdTxtBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2).Trim <> "" Then

            'Check if Month is entered.
            If mskdTxtBox1.Text.Substring(3, 2).Trim <> "" Then

                'Check if year is not entered.
                If mskdTxtBox1.Text.Length = 6 Then

                    'Check if Date and month entered are valid.
                    If IsDate(mskdTxtBox1.Text & Now.Year) Then
                        mskdTxtBox1.Text = mskdTxtBox1.Text & Now.Year
                    End If

                End If

            Else

                'Check if Date entered will be valid for the current date that we want to create?
                If IsDate(mskdTxtBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2).Trim & "-" & Now.Month & "-" & Now.Year) Then

                    'Check if month is two digit?
                    If Now.Month.ToString.Length < 2 Then
                        mskdTxtBox1.Text = mskdTxtBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2).Trim & "-0" & Now.Month & "-" & Now.Year
                    Else
                        mskdTxtBox1.Text = mskdTxtBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2).Trim & "-" & Now.Month & "-" & Now.Year
                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Else

            Dim TodaysDay As String = Now.Day
            Dim TodaysMonth As String = Now.Month

            'Check if Current day is two digit?
            If Now.Day < 10 Then
                TodaysDay = "0" & Now.Day
            End If

            'Check if Current Month is two digit?
            If Now.Month < 10 Then
                TodaysMonth = "0" & Now.Month
            End If

            mskdTxtBox1.Text = TodaysDay & "-" & TodaysMonth & "-" & Now.Year

        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different questions here and it's not terribly clear what you really want, but to answer your question about getting the current day/month/year, check out [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).

```
DateTime.Now.Day gets you the current day

DateTime.Now.Month gets you the current month

DateTime.Now.Year gets you the current year
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I know about now object.

Comment: @Vishal Then what is your question? Do you have any code you'd like to post that shows you've attempted the problem? Looks like you have a pretty clear picture of what behavior you want, were you looking for someone to code it for you?

Comment: No. I don't want someone to code for me. My Question is more clarified in third comment of question. I want someone to give me the correct logic that if user has entered only date in the masked textbox or he has entered date and month or has he entered the whole date?

Comment: Your comment doesn't really make any sense. If (conditions) then WHAT? You want logic to detect which one of those conditions is true?

Comment: There's a pretty huge gap in logic you can't possibly implement. The only condition you can really detect is if they've entered the whole date. Otherwise something like `5/10` is totally ambiguous. It could be a day/month or month/year. What really is the issue here is [The X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about checking these conditions when the *real* issue is *why* you're even trying to check them to begin with.

Comment: You are right. We can get X Y Problem. But if we assume that user will always enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format then is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx). That will return true if what they've entered is a valid date.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I got the solution by using substring method.

Comment: @Vishal You should edit your original question and include the solution that resolved the question.